# Are there any gstreamer plugins to expand a video stream?

Tags: linux, gstreamer, multimedia

My gstreamer version is 0.10 and I want to expand a 16:9 video to 4:3 by inserting blanks at top and bottom.

I searched the plugin list with gst-inspect. There're "videoscale" and "videocrop", but no "videoexpand".

Are there any plugins that directly do the job?

Edit: The problem has been solved. The "videobox" filter just fit my demand.

Comment: you can post your solution here, it will prevent others from asking the same question once more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `videobox` filter. It can produce letterboxed video for any aspect ratio. It's also useful for compositing a smaller video on top of a larger one by adding a transparent border to match the larger video's size (see http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gstreamer/347-more-gstreamer-tips-picture-in-picture-compositing).

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new to stackoverflow, I wasn't allowed to post two links. You might like to check [this](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/)  as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll drop my two cents here as this post lead me to the solution for what I think is a related problem (scaling** input video of indeterminate resolution and aspect ratio to a display with a fixed resolution):

**Adding `add-borders=true` to the `videoscale` element will preserve aspect ratio by padding letter/pillar -boxes as necessary.**

One minor caveat for me, as my project was working with dynamic input for which statically defining AR would be problematic, was ensuring a caps filter containing `pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1` was in my pipeline, to define the output AR (in concert the `height` and `width` params specified alongside `pixel-aspect-ratio`).

** *Though you can still benefit from `add-borders` even when not scaling—the documentation calls out that it is "safe to insert this element in a pipeline [...] without any cost if no scaling is needed."*

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use ffmpeg for that.

Check below link

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  But the expanding (maybe should be called padding) operation is just a part of a long encoder/filter chain, and I currently have no plan to move the whole chain from gstreamer to ffmpeg.  I have found that the filter "videobox" solves my problem.